# How can I achieve more realism in this given scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, photorealism

I've been working on this project in Cycles for quite some time now and it's probably my first project I created and rendered in blender (besides creating some simple shapes before but not rendering them). I've been trying to tweak different settings, materials, lighting and use the filmic colors from blenderguru's video to achieve somewhat realistic effect but those renders still look fairly "artificial" and as if someone pulled them from a game, instead of looking photo-realistic. Something just seems "off" in this renders.
I'm running out of ideas on how to make these scenes look more photo-like. I'd be thankful if someone could look at it from a "fresh eye" perspective and hopefully point out what I could've missed or forgot to do while creating them.

Render of the car washing station with a blur and slight colour correction in GIMP
[image: Render with a blur and slight colour correction in GIMP]

Render of the car washing station without the blur
[image]

Render of the car washing station during night, with some lights (emission nodes)
[image]

Comment: As it stands this question is mostly opinion based or artistic critique. For that it is probably best to ask over at blenderartist forum

Answer (score 3):

Work on the details and imperfections(cracks,  scratches, etc.). 
Add more assets as you can.  I believe there is no car wash that is sitting alone in a parkway. From simple things like debris and trash cans to more complex scenery like cars and humans will make your scene complete.

Try to reduce low-quality textures for the building and try to model it yourself using procedural materials. 90% of realism is focused on lighting, materials, and scaling.

And I don't think StackExchange is a good place for critics and specific requests, try [Blender Artists](https://www.blenderartists.org) instead.